# What does 'APPLY' or 'APPLY FOR' condition mean in sequence?

Tags: webmethods

[image: APPLY condition in sequence]

Can anyone please help me understand what will the sequence check for value field or what does 'APPLY' and 'APPLY FOR' mean?

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple string comparison. You check if the variable "value" equals the string "APPLY" or (double pipe ||)"APPLY FOR".
The two BRANCH steps below the sequence with your condition do not make sense. Neither does the comment at the first branch, since the condition is clearly not checking for digits only.